# How to access the unique ID generated from firestore before creating the document in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to access the auto-generated UID that firestore created before creating the document.

I added an ID to match for the ID that has been generated.

[image]

I used the const `hardcodedText` as an example and get the `hardcodedText.id` to access the new id but it's giving me error. I also tried accessing it using `doc(hardcodedText.id)` but it's also not working.

```
import { db } from "./firebase";
import { addDoc, collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

function fetchTodo() {

  const hardcodedText = {
    todo: "Throw Trash", id: hardcodedText.id
  };
  addDoc(collection(db, "todos"), hardcodedText);

  console.log(hardcodedText.id)
}
```

Basically I wanted to add a specific field for `ID` that has been generated in the middle  after creating a document

[image]

Comment: Did you see the third code-sample in the documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)? That explicitly says: "In some cases, it can be useful to create a document reference with an auto-generated ID, then use the reference later. For this use case, you can call `doc()`...", but check the link for the full example.